# Получить индекс заголовка столбца

Tags: java, массивы, csv

Всем доброго времени суток! Делаю одно задание и столкнулся с небольшой трудностью.
У меня есть некий csv файл с названиями столбцов - `(За период;Учетный месяц;Дата документа;Создан;Тип;Расход;Сумма;Статус)`. С помощью csvreader я читаю его:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("LS-1.csv"), ';');

List<String[]> lines = reader.readAll();

String[] lineName = lines.get(0);
```

Как мне узнать ИНДЕКС вот этой нулевой строки где прописано "За период" и "Сумма"?? Т.к. мне в дальнейшем нужно будет использовать эти индесы для взятия значений из этих столбцов

Comment: Я не совсем понял, что вы хотите сделать. Нашел хорошую статью как распарсить csv сразу в объект - я думаю это должно вам помочь
https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-opencsv/

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [CSVReaderHeaderAware](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReaderHeaderAware.html) вместо `CSVReader` и тогда сможете получать значения по именам столбцов, а не по индексам.